# | | acting like && and vice versa in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got a JQUERY-AJAX that checks if my checkbox is checked in html , and if it is, i store the result in 2 variable : preferCall and preferEmail , as true or false .

```
  var preferCall = false;  
           if($('input[name="prefer-call"]').is(':checked')){  
              preferCall = true;
          }

  var preferEmail = false;  
           if($('input[name="prefer-email"]').is(':checked')){  
              preferEmail = true;
          }
```

Then I'm stringifying this boolean result in ajax :

```
 preferEmail: JSON.stringify(preferEmail)
                                                   
 preferCall: JSON.stringify(preferCall)
```

And then in php, i need this "if statement" to be true, if any of these 2 checkboxs are checked :

But instead , || acts like && , and && acts like || and && combined

```
elseif ( ($preferEmail !== "true") || ($preferCall !== "true") ) { 
    $errorEmptyPreference = true; }
```

The reason why I'm converting the boolean variables to strings is because in php , the "if statement" wasn't working just by doing simply ( &preferEmail =! true ) , it was always finding this statement true.

I'm attaching the full code would look like as well :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#contact-form").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
 
 var preferEmail = false;   
 if($('input[name="prefer-email"]').is(':checked')){  
 preferEmail = true; }   
 
 var preferCall = false;   
 if($('input[name="prefer-call"]').is(':checked')){  
 preferCall = true; }   

 $.ajax({
url: "../php/contact.php",
type: "POST",

data: {                           
preferEmail: JSON.stringify(preferEmail), 
preferCall: JSON.stringify(preferCall),
submit: submit},
success: function (event) {
    $('#hidden').html(event);      }
});

   });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="../php/contact.php"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="prefer-email" name="prefer-email" value="prefer-email">
<input type='checkbox' id="prefer-call" name="prefer-call" value="prefer-call">
<button id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-button place-button">SEND</button>
</form>
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$preferEmail = $_POST['preferEmail'];
$preferCall = $_POST['preferCall'];
$errorEmptyPrefererence = false;
if ( ($preferEmail !== "true") || ($preferCall !== "true") ) {
$errorEmptyPreference = true; }
}
?>
```

Can anyone explain me why is this happening ?

Comment: `var_dump($preferEmail, $preferCall, $preferEmail !== "true",  $preferCall !== "true", ($preferEmail !== "true" || $preferCall !== "true"))` gives what?

Comment: not sure what do you want me to check

Comment: The values, run that code and provide output.

Comment: You test, as it stands, is “if either one of these is not true”, which you can see here: https://3v4l.org/DG2V0